# Reverse Geocode a location in Japan

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use the reverse Geo-coding API of HERE. When I try it for the locations in Japan, I am not able to get the correct results. Does it support addresses in Japan?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should show us your code so we know what exactly might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

HERE doesn't offer street level detailed maps for Japan. Therefore the Geocoder API only returns high level results.

Answer (score 1):

It saids on the [official site](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/coverage-geocoder.html) that:

> Note: As stated in the table below, we provide entry map coverage for Japan and South Korea through this API, but we are able to provide full coverage via separate services. For more information or to license access to Japan or South Korea geocoding with full coverage, contact us.

I really don't know why, but it may have to do with confusing addresses that requires different kind of API. I live in Japan and we don't have street names unlike most other countries!

Comment: just realized now that this question was asked 3 years ago... haha